# Why does GCC say "named return values no longer supported"?

Tags: c++, gcc

I accidentally put the opening brace of my function definition after the return statement

```
int id(int k) return k; { }
```

But GCC answered with a weird error message

> error: named return values are no longer supported

Can anyone please explain what that weird feature might be? I've never heard about it.

Comment: maybe some early implementation of NRVO where you had to name the variable to get it to elide the copy?

Comment: Go has named result parameters, http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html#SEC106) - early NRVO implementation by explicit definition of the named return value in the function header.

Native support for NRVO without this extension was added [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.1/changes.html) - GCC 3.1 Release Series.

Brief cut and paste for context:

> G++ now supports the "named return
>   value optimization": for code like
>
> ```
> A f () {
>   A a;
>   ...
>   return a;
> }
> ```
>
> G++ will allocate a in the return
>   value slot, so that the return becomes
>   a no-op. For this to work, all return
>   statements in the function must return
>   the same variable.

Comment: NRVO is a subject near to my heart after spending a long time trying to work out why the heck VC++ 7.1 (which is the last Microsoft C++ to have no NRVO) is so slow when returning large `vector` results...

Comment: isn't there also something in VC++2008 like no NRVO in debug builds ?

Comment: @Matthieu - that would not surprise me, debug Visual C++ universally favours debuggability over performance (see 'checked STL', for example).  All I know for sure is that NRVO first came into Visual C++ in VC8.

Comment: It is an old thing.  Dating back at least to 2.4.5, June 93.  There were other experimental things in g++ (I remember min/max operators, signatures which are precursor of go interface,...) around that time.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html)

They were [removed in gcc3.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html)

Answer (score 2):

This was a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html#SEC106), [removed in GCC 3.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html).

Answer (score -1):

//you can see the difference first one is giving a return error and second one is working fine.....

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename t> t sum(const t a, const t b) return a + b;

int main() {
    cout << sum<int>(1, 2);



}
```

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

```
template<typename t> t sum(const t a, const t b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    cout << sum<int>(1, 2);


}
```