# Explicitly named return values?

Tags: return-value, raku

In Go ([and G++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4246514/4532996)), the following is a common idiom:

```golang
func sqr(x int) (n int, err error) {
    n = x * x
    err = nil
    return
}
```

The `(n int, err error)` explicitly enumerates the name and type of the return values. There are in my opinion lots of advantages to this, and I like it.

---

In Perl 6, we can:

```perl
my sub sqr (Int:D $x) returns Int:D {
    $x ** 2;
}
```

The return is implicit, which makes me kind of uncomfortable  (we could make it explicit with `return`), but you may notice the return *type* is specified (as is the fact it's <sub>`D`efined</sub>).

Unsurprisingly, there's no obvious way to return a value explicitly by name, but I'm curious, since Perl (especially 6) is extensively modifiable in every way, if there's a way to implement this.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> However hacky it may be, but too hacky and I'd avoid using it for "real" things.

Comment: Why would you want to force a return value to be returned as a specifically named variable? Doesn't that make it harder to reuse your function? +1 for explaining Perl 6 syntax, including `:D`.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: why not? and there are indeed issues with implicitly returning the value of the last expression - eg in Perl6, there was that whole thing about for loops in tail position becoming lazy because they were not sunk...

Comment: If you want something that is named, you can return a `Pair` such as `square => $x ** 2`, but then your return type will need to be `Pair`. I suppose you could create as specific of a type as you desire and enforce it.

Comment: @Christoph *why not?* You sure sound like a Perl programmer! :)

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms because I like things explicit, gosh darnit! On a more serious note, if I'm gonna have lengthy subroutines (but without violating my version of [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (which is essentially that functions should do one thing and do it well)) then I want them to be self-documenting and maintainable.

Comment: @Christoph those're the cases under which explicit `return`s are a really good idea, but even better if I can have `return` in the *signature* instead of the last line!

Comment: @cat Interesting from a self-documenting point of view. Do you want the named variables that are returned to have that name in the scope that they are returned to, or do their names just refer to what they are named inside the subroutine? I really like this idea, in the case of the latter.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms No, the name (obviously) refers to the subroutine's scope. [Take a look at this, for instance](http://play.golang.org/p/hcKG8v-o3u).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I really like this idea.

Comment: I like the look of that. I'm pretty sure neither standard Perl 6 nor stock Rakudo can yet do what you suggest. Maybe in Devali or later the `-->` syntax / `returns` trait could take a signature (so an "output args list" for the routine like the existing "input args" one). The signature's parameters would declare new lexical rw variables in the routines body. No values would be assigned during routine entry. The `return`'s arg list would be typechecked against the return signature. @cat, maybe ask on the freenode #perl6 IRC channel about doing this in module space and/or in Devali.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all else fails, you can always write your own slang.

However, here are two less involved approaches I came up with, the first one using a dynamic variable of fixed name, the second one using an `rw` parameter of user-defined name:

```perl6
multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Routine:D \r, :$dynrv!) {
    r.wrap(-> | { my $*rv; callsame; $*rv })
}

multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Routine:D \r, :$pararv!) {
    r.wrap(-> |c { my $rv; callwith(|c, $rv); $rv })
}

sub double($x) is dynrv {
    $*rv = $x * 2;
    return 666; # discarded
}

sub triple($x, $y is rw) is pararv {
    $y = $x * 3;
    return 666; # discarded
}

say double 42;
say triple 42;
```

Note that this only supports a single return value, though I have some ideas how multiple ones could be made to work...

---

#### *edit:* Eg this way:

```perl6
multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Routine:D \r, :@dynrv!) {
    r.wrap(-> | {
        my @rv = Nil xx @dynrv;
        my $*rv = Map.new(@dynrv Z=> @rv);
        callsame;
        @dynrv > 1 ?? @rv !! @rv[0];
    })
}

multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Routine:D \r, Int :$pararv!) {
    r.wrap(-> |c {
        my @rv = Nil xx $pararv;
        callwith(|c, |@rv);
        $pararv > 1 ?? @rv !! @rv[0];
    })
}

sub divmod($a, $b) is dynrv<d m> {
    $*rv<d> = $a div $b;
    $*rv<m> = $a mod $b;
}

sub plusmin($a, $b, $p is rw, $m is rw) is pararv(2) {
    $p = $a + $b;
    $m = $a - $b;
}

say divmod 14, 3;
say plusmin 14, 3;
```

Comment: this is *awesome*. It's **crazy**, but it's awesome.

Answer (score 4):

While slangs can be used to get exactly what you want, I believe they're the wrong size solution to this problem.  Firstly, cat's *Go* example is returning error information as well as an (Int).  I'd suggest the Perl 6 way for that is to simply return a *Fail* object using `&fail` which the caller can test for using `.defined` or the `//` operator;

```perl6
if $something_wrong {
  return fail "Dang!  Even the squaring function isn't working today."
}
else {
  return $x ** 2
}
```

I know this doesn't document the dual return values as requested, but do you want to use an explicit variable for exceptional out-of-band data?     What if it wasn't error data but other information?
Let's assume we want to return an (Int) with an Easter-egg message.  In this case, as the extra data is a different type, (Str), we can run-time mixin a role with a `.Str` method that returns the message if the return value is used in string context.

```perl6
return $x * $x but "Suprise!  Bet you weren't expecting that!"
```

Alternatively, if the extra data is of the same type we can explicitly mixin an anonymous role.  Let's say we want to return an (Int) with a `.size` property;

```perl6
return $x but role { has $.size = calculate_size() }
```

Finally, you can document your return type explicitly by declaring the role and then using a subset to define your own (Int) type that demands the role;

```perl6
role Size { has UInt:D $.size = 0 }
subset MyInt of Int where Size;

sub sqr(Int:D $x, UInt:D :$size = 12) returns MyInt:D {
  return $x * $x but Size($size)
}

my $square5 = sqr(5);
say "5 squared is $square5 with size $square5.size()."
# prints: 5 squared is 25 with size 12.
```

Details are in [S14](http://design.perl6.org/S14.html) and [S12 - Anonymous mixin roles](http://design.perl6.org/S12.html#Anonymous_Mixin_Roles_using_but_or_does)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the amazing answer reminding me that Go != Perl 6, and secondly, +1 for "Dang!  Even the squaring function isn't working today." just because it made me laugh :-)

Comment: ...does P6 really have a `but` keyword. Well, I don't know why I'm surprised.